# How can install Django project requirement.txt with python script

Tags: python, django, python-3.5

I am creating a single script for setup and running whole Django project.

```
venv_parent_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),os.pardir))
venv_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(venv_parent_dir, 'fvenv'))
subprocess.run(args=['virtualenv', '-p', 'python3', venv_dir])
os.popen('/bin/bash --rcfile %s'%(venv_dir+'/bin/activate'))
```

With the above code I created a virtual environment then activate this. Now I want to install the `requirements.txt` file in the activated virtual environment

```
subprocess.run(args=['pip3', 'install', '-r', 'requirements.txt'])
```

I tried with `subprocess`, but it's not installing in the virtual environment, it is installing in the operating system Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A the moment, the `os.popen` command does not affect the environment that `subprocess.run` runs in. That means that your `subprocess.run` call is using the system `pip3` instead of the `pip` from the virtualenv. You can use the `pip` from the virtualenv by using the full path:

```
import os
pip = os.path.join(venv_dir, 'bin', 'pip')
subprocess.run(args=[pip, 'install', '-r', 'requirements.txt'])
```

By using `/path/to/venv/bin/pip`, you don't have to activate the virtual environment first.

Comment: Thanks alot sir,@ Alasdair

Comment: could you please tell me, better way to activate the environment. instead of os.popen('/bin/bash --rcfile %s'%(venv_dir+'/bin/activate'))

Comment: Not off the top of my head, no. Consider what activating the virtual environment is doing, and whether you really need that in the Python script. You don't need the bash prompt or `deactivate` function. If all you need is the `$PATH` environment variable, then you can modify `os.environ['PATH']`. However I think that using the full path to `pip` as in my answer is probably a better approach.